# Lines return "NaNs" when within a switch; some of these same lines operate flawlessly when the switch is commented out

Tags: c, switch-statement, nan

When I run my program (using gcc -std=c99 -lm) with a switch statement, all of the "factors" calculated in this Case 1:

```
factors[rows][0]=cbrtf((3+(float)scores[rows][1])/(3+(float)scores[rows][3]));
```

are reported as "NaN".  If I comment out Cases 2 and 3, the same line runs flawlessly.  Can anyone explain this?

As a separate issue, Cases 2:

```
factors[rows][0]=((float)scores[rows][1])/(((float)scores[rows][1])+((float)scores[rows][3]));
```

and 3:

```
factors[rows][0]=log((((float)scores[rows][1])/(((float)scores[rows][1])+((float)scores[rows][3])))+1);
```

result in NaNs whether within or outside of the switch.  I've checked my parentheses a dozen times.  There's no possibility of division by zero (since the sum of the scores in the denominators must be positive), and to prevent taking the natural logarithm of zero, which is undefined, I have added 1 to a quotient which always falls between 0 and 1 inclusive. Why do these lines produce NaNs?

This is the first program I've written since Intro to Fortran IV in 1973, so it may be something obvious . . .

Here's part of the data file (data.csv):

```
home_id,home_team,home_points,away_id,away_team,away_points
98,Western Kentucky,38,2046,Austin Peay,27
77,Northwestern,31,158,Nebraska,28
2439,UNLV,52,304,Idaho State,21
356,Illinois,38,2751,Wyoming,6
328,Utah State,31,41,Connecticut,20
52,Florida State,47,2184,Duquesne,7
2226,Florida Atlantic,43,2429,Charlotte,13
153,North Carolina,56,50,Florida A&M,24
2638,UTEP,13,249,North Texas,31
166,New Mexico State,12,2440,Nevada,23
62,Hawai'i,10,238,Vanderbilt,63
2006,Akron,30,2598,St Francis (PA),23
2116,UCF,56,2569,South Carolina State,10
2633,Tennessee,59,2050,Ball State,10
221,Pittsburgh,38,277,West Virginia,31
197,Oklahoma State,58,2117,Central Michigan,44
2649,Toledo,37,112358,Long Island University,0
2229,Florida International,38,2803,Bryant,37
154,Wake Forest,44,2678,VMI,10
2509,Purdue,31,213,Penn State,35
2459,Northern Illinois,34,2197,Eastern Illinois,27
142,Missouri,52,2348,Louisiana Tech,24
5,UAB,59,2010,Alabama A&M,0
135,Minnesota,38,166,New Mexico State,0
9,Arizona State,40,2464,Northern Arizona,3
23,San José State,21,2502,Portland State,17
278,Fresno State,35,13,Cal Poly,7
2429,Charlotte,24,2729,William & Mary,41
2199,Eastern Michigan,42,2198,Eastern Kentucky,34
127,Michigan State,35,2711,Western Michigan,13
295,Old Dominion,20,259,Virginia Tech,17
150,Duke,30,218,Temple,0
84,Indiana,23,356,Illinois,20
2305,Kansas,56,2635,Tennessee Tech,10
38,Colorado,13,2628,TCU,38
151,East Carolina,20,152,NC State,21
2426,Navy,7,48,Delaware,14
103,Boston College,21,164,Rutgers,22
41,Connecticut,28,2115,Central Connecticut,3
120,Maryland,31,2084,Buffalo,10
2026,Appalachian State,61,153,North Carolina,63
245,Texas A&M,31,2534,Sam Houston State,0
130,Michigan,51,36,Colorado State,7
2294,Iowa,7,2571,South Dakota State,3
258,Virginia,34,257,Richmond,17
2005,Air Force,48,2460,Northern Iowa,17
66,Iowa State,42,2546,Southeast Missouri State,10
26,UCLA,45,189,Bowling Green,17
21,San Diego State,20,12,Arizona,38
2751,Wyoming,40,202,Tulsa,37
201,Oklahoma,45,2638,UTEP,13
276,Marshall,55,2450,Norfolk State,3
2390,Miami,70,2065,Bethune-Cookman,13
2636,UT San Antonio,35,248,Houston,37
61,Georgia,49,2483,Oregon,3
158,Nebraska,38,155,North Dakota,17
8,Arkansas,31,2132,Cincinnati,24
58,South Florida,21,252,BYU,50
25,California,34,302,UC Davis,13
145,Ole Miss,28,2653,Troy,10
6,South Alabama,48,2447,Nicholls,7
2440,Nevada,38,326,Texas State,14
256,James Madison,44,2393,Middle Tennessee,7
290,Georgia Southern,59,2415,Morgan State,7
30,USC,66,242,Rice,14
195,Ohio,41,2226,Florida Atlantic,38
57,Florida,29,254,Utah,26
275,Wisconsin,38,2287,Illinois State,0
309,Louisiana,24,2545,Southeastern Louisiana,7
2572,Southern Mississippi,27,2335,Liberty,29
238,Vanderbilt,42,2210,Elon,31
2,Auburn,42,2382,Mercer,16
2655,Tulane,42,113,UMass,10
324,Coastal Carolina,38,349,Army,28
96,Kentucky,37,193,Miami (OH),13
239,Baylor,69,399,Albany,10
2032,Arkansas State,58,2755,Grambling,3
2306,Kansas State,34,233,South Dakota,0
344,Mississippi State,49,235,Memphis,23
333,Alabama,55,328,Utah State,0
2579,South Carolina,35,2247,Georgia State,14
194,Ohio State,21,87,Notre Dame,10
249,North Texas,10,2567,SMU,48
24,Stanford,41,2142,Colgate,10
251,Texas,52,2433,Louisiana Monroe,10
2641,Texas Tech,63,93,Murray State,10
183,Syracuse,31,97,Louisville,7
167,New Mexico,41,311,Maine,0
265,Washington State,24,70,Idaho,17
204,Oregon State,34,68,Boise State,17
264,Washington,45,2309,Kent State,20
62,Hawai'i,17,98,Western Kentucky,49
52,Florida State,24,99,LSU,23
59,Georgia Tech,10,228,Clemson,41
5,UAB,24,193,Miami (OH),20
2653,Troy,18,2636,UT San Antonio,12
97,Louisville,24,2132,Cincinnati,7
204,Oregon State,30,57,Florida,3
278,Fresno State,29,265,Washington State,6
2572,Southern Mississippi,38,242,Rice,24
252,BYU,24,2567,SMU,23
68,Boise State,35,249,North Texas,32
41,Connecticut,14,276,Marshall,28
23,San José State,27,2199,Eastern Michigan,41
2649,Toledo,21,2335,Liberty,19
6,South Alabama,23,98,Western Kentucky,44
2005,Air Force,30,239,Baylor,15
248,Houston,23,309,Louisiana,16
142,Missouri,17,154,Wake Forest,27
21,San Diego State,23,2393,Middle Tennessee,25
189,Bowling Green,19,166,New Mexico State,24
2084,Buffalo,23,290,Georgia Southern,21
328,Utah State,10,235,Memphis,38
151,East Carolina,53,324,Coastal Carolina,29
197,Oklahoma State,17,275,Wisconsin,24
150,Duke,30,2116,UCF,13
8,Arkansas,55,2305,Kansas,53
153,North Carolina,27,2483,Oregon,28
145,Ole Miss,25,2641,Texas Tech,42
135,Minnesota,28,183,Syracuse,20
52,Florida State,35,201,Oklahoma,32
264,Washington,27,251,Texas,20
152,NC State,12,120,Maryland,16
26,UCLA,35,221,Pittsburgh,37
2579,South Carolina,38,87,Notre Dame,45
2751,Wyoming,27,195,Ohio,30
228,Clemson,14,2633,Tennessee,31
2306,Kansas State,20,333,Alabama,45
96,Kentucky,0,2294,Iowa,21
130,Michigan,45,2628,TCU,51
61,Georgia,42,194,Ohio State,41
356,Illinois,10,344,Mississippi State,19
30,USC,45,2655,Tulane,46
2509,Purdue,7,99,LSU,63
254,Utah,21,213,Penn State,35
61,Georgia,65,2628,TCU,7
2116,UCF,14,97,Louisville,20
167,New Mexico,14,68,Boise State,31
8,Arkansas,44,2579,South Carolina,30
194,Ohio State,45,2032,Arkansas State,12
251,Texas,19,333,Alabama,20
349,Army,38,2636,UT San Antonio,41
213,Penn State,46,195,Ohio,10
2306,Kansas State,40,142,Missouri,12
2247,Georgia State,28,153,North Carolina,35
77,Northwestern,23,150,Duke,31
135,Minnesota,62,2710,Western Illinois,10
2390,Miami,30,2572,Southern Mississippi,7
238,Vanderbilt,25,154,Wake Forest,45
152,NC State,55,2127,Charleston Southern,3
2117,Central Michigan,24,6,South Alabama,38
254,Utah,73,253,Southern Utah,7
218,Temple,30,322,Lafayette,14
2050,Ball State,30,2711,Western Michigan,37
87,Notre Dame,21,276,Marshall,26
221,Pittsburgh,27,2633,Tennessee,34
2429,Charlotte,21,120,Maryland,56
2132,Cincinnati,63,338,Kennesaw State,10
228,Clemson,35,231,Furman,12
2005,Air Force,41,38,Colorado,10
2426,Navy,13,235,Memphis,37
275,Wisconsin,14,265,Washington State,17
245,Texas A&M,14,2026,Appalachian State,17
127,Michigan State,52,2006,Akron,0
256,James Madison,63,2450,Norfolk State,7
2641,Texas Tech,33,248,Houston,30
189,Bowling Green,57,2198,Eastern Kentucky,59
25,California,20,2439,UNLV,14
2294,Iowa,7,66,Iowa State,10
356,Illinois,24,258,Virginia,3
164,Rutgers,66,2681,Wagner,7
2509,Purdue,56,282,Indiana State,0
2751,Wyoming,33,2458,Northern Colorado,10
264,Washington,52,2502,Portland State,6
61,Georgia,33,2535,Samford,0
36,Colorado State,19,2393,Middle Tennessee,34
26,UCLA,45,2011,Alabama State,7
2440,Nevada,41,2916,Incarnate Word,55
324,Coastal Carolina,31,2241,Gardner-Webb,27
2335,Liberty,21,5,UAB,14
2084,Buffalo,31,107,Holy Cross,37
151,East Carolina,39,295,Old Dominion,21
2226,Florida Atlantic,42,2545,Southeastern Louisiana,9
277,West Virginia,42,2305,Kansas,55
193,Miami (OH),31,2523,Robert Morris,14
2655,Tulane,52,2016,Alcorn State,0
201,Oklahoma,33,2309,Kent State,3
309,Louisiana,49,2199,Eastern Michigan,21
326,Texas State,41,2229,Florida International,12
58,South Florida,42,47,Howard,20
2567,SMU,45,2320,Lamar,16
328,Utah State,7,2692,Weber State,35
2649,Toledo,55,113,UMass,10
59,Georgia Tech,35,2717,Western Carolina,17
41,Connecticut,14,183,Syracuse,48
57,Florida,16,96,Kentucky,26
145,Ole Miss,59,2110,Central Arkansas,3
2653,Troy,38,2010,Alabama A&M,17
202,Tulsa,38,2459,Northern Illinois,35
2348,Louisiana Tech,52,2617,Stephen F. Austin,17
197,Oklahoma State,34,9,Arizona State,17
249,North Texas,59,2640,Texas Southern,27
242,Rice,52,2377,McNeese,10
2,Auburn,24,23,San José State,16
24,Stanford,28,30,USC,41
99,LSU,65,2582,Southern,17
158,Nebraska,42,290,Georgia Southern,45
21,San Diego State,38,304,Idaho State,7
2628,TCU,59,2627,Tarleton State,17
259,Virginia Tech,27,103,Boston College,10
130,Michigan,56,62,Hawai'i,10
84,Indiana,35,70,Idaho,22
2433,Louisiana Monroe,35,2447,Nicholls,7
2483,Oregon,70,331,Eastern Washington,14
2638,UTEP,20,166,New Mexico State,13
252,BYU,26,239,Baylor,20
278,Fresno State,32,204,Oregon State,35
12,Arizona,17,344,Mississippi State,39
97,Louisville,31,52,Florida State,35
2751,Wyoming,17,2005,Air Force,14
259,Virginia Tech,27,2747,Wofford,7
96,Kentucky,31,2754,Youngstown State,0
77,Northwestern,24,79,Southern Illinois,31
183,Syracuse,32,2509,Purdue,29
142,Missouri,34,2000,Abilene Christian,17
2579,South Carolina,7,61,Georgia,48
84,Indiana,33,98,Western Kentucky,30
158,Nebraska,14,201,Oklahoma,49
2309,Kent State,63,112358,Long Island University,10
193,Miami (OH),17,2132,Cincinnati,38
239,Baylor,42,326,Texas State,7
349,Army,49,222,Villanova,10
130,Michigan,59,41,Connecticut,0
324,Coastal Carolina,38,2084,Buffalo,26
277,West Virginia,65,119,Towson,7
2117,Central Michigan,41,2083,Bucknell,0
218,Temple,14,164,Rutgers,16
258,Virginia,16,295,Old Dominion,14
2050,Ball State,31,93,Murray State,0
26,UCLA,32,6,South Alabama,31
66,Iowa State,43,195,Ohio,10
87,Notre Dame,24,25,California,17
2439,UNLV,58,249,North Texas,27
2306,Kansas State,10,2655,Tulane,17
5,UAB,35,290,Georgia Southern,21
59,Georgia Tech,0,145,Ole Miss,42
2483,Oregon,41,252,BYU,20
275,Wisconsin,66,166,New Mexico State,7
2459,Northern Illinois,28,238,Vanderbilt,38
135,Minnesota,49,38,Colorado,7
2026,Appalachian State,32,2653,Troy,28
2,Auburn,12,213,Penn State,41
113,UMass,20,2619,Stony Brook,3
68,Boise State,30,2630,UT Martin,7
248,Houston,30,2305,Kansas,48
333,Alabama,63,2433,Louisiana Monroe,7
189,Bowling Green,34,276,Marshall,31
265,Washington State,38,36,Colorado State,7
154,Wake Forest,37,2335,Liberty,36
99,LSU,31,344,Mississippi State,16
150,Duke,49,2448,North Carolina A&T,20
151,East Carolina,49,2097,Campbell,10
197,Oklahoma State,63,2029,Arkansas-Pine Bluff,7
152,NC State,27,2641,Texas Tech,14
2633,Tennessee,63,2006,Akron,6
235,Memphis,44,2032,Arkansas State,32
2572,Southern Mississippi,64,2466,Northwestern State,10
8,Arkansas,38,2623,Missouri State,27
194,Ohio State,77,2649,Toledo,21
2393,Middle Tennessee,49,2634,Tennessee State,6
202,Tulsa,54,55,Jacksonville State,17
2247,Georgia State,41,2429,Charlotte,42
2711,Western Michigan,13,221,Pittsburgh,34
264,Washington,39,127,Michigan State,28
2226,Florida Atlantic,14,2116,UCF,40
242,Rice,33,309,Louisiana,21
120,Maryland,34,2567,SMU,27
57,Florida,31,58,South Florida,28
103,Boston College,38,311,Maine,17
2294,Iowa,27,2440,Nevada,0
167,New Mexico,27,2638,UTEP,10
251,Texas,41,2636,UT San Antonio,20
228,Clemson,48,2348,Louisiana Tech,20
204,Oregon State,68,147,Montana State,28
245,Texas A&M,17,2390,Miami,9
254,Utah,35,21,San Diego State,7
30,USC,45,278,Fresno State,17
12,Arizona,31,2449,North Dakota State,28
9,Arizona State,21,2199,Eastern Michigan,30
62,Hawai'i,24,2184,Duquesne,14
2247,Georgia State,24,324,Coastal Carolina,41
259,Virginia Tech,10,277,West Virginia,33
356,Illinois,31,236,Chattanooga,0
183,Syracuse,22,258,Virginia,20
2005,Air Force,48,2440,Nevada,20
2638,UTEP,27,68,Boise State,10
344,Mississippi State,45,189,Bowling Green,14
2,Auburn,17,142,Missouri,14
2199,Eastern Michigan,31,2084,Buffalo,50
130,Michigan,34,120,Maryland,27
2567,SMU,34,2628,TCU,42
61,Georgia,39,2309,Kent State,22
97,Louisville,41,58,South Florida,3
2305,Kansas,35,150,Duke,27
213,Penn State,33,2117,Central Michigan,14
66,Iowa State,24,239,Baylor,31
154,Wake Forest,45,228,Clemson,51
221,Pittsburgh,45,227,Rhode Island,24
38,Colorado,17,26,UCLA,45
218,Temple,28,113,UMass,0
195,Ohio,59,2230,Fordham,52
2633,Tennessee,38,57,Florida,33
98,Western Kentucky,73,2229,Florida International,0
21,San Diego State,17,2649,Toledo,14
235,Memphis,44,249,North Texas,34
153,North Carolina,32,87,Notre Dame,45
2641,Texas Tech,37,251,Texas,34
2636,UT San Antonio,52,2640,Texas Southern,24
2390,Miami,31,2393,Middle Tennessee,45
2026,Appalachian State,28,256,James Madison,32
2132,Cincinnati,45,84,Indiana,24
127,Michigan State,7,135,Minnesota,34
2116,UCF,27,59,Georgia Tech,10
36,Colorado State,10,16,Sacramento State,41
145,Ole Miss,35,202,Tulsa,27
265,Washington State,41,2483,Oregon,44
25,California,49,12,Arizona,31
290,Georgia Southern,34,2050,Ball State,23
248,Houston,34,242,Rice,27
151,East Carolina,20,2426,Navy,23
2335,Liberty,21,2006,Akron,12
295,Old Dominion,29,2032,Arkansas State,26
328,Utah State,24,2439,UNLV,34
6,South Alabama,38,2348,Louisiana Tech,14
2655,Tulane,24,2572,Southern Mississippi,27
326,Texas State,34,2277,Houston Christian,0
245,Texas A&M,23,8,Arkansas,21
164,Rutgers,10,2294,Iowa,27
96,Kentucky,31,2459,Northern Illinois,23
2653,Troy,16,276,Marshall,7
333,Alabama,55,238,Vanderbilt,3
99,LSU,38,167,New Mexico,0
152,NC State,41,41,Connecticut,10
194,Ohio State,52,275,Wisconsin,21
2579,South Carolina,56,2429,Charlotte,20
2509,Purdue,28,2226,Florida Atlantic,26
77,Northwestern,14,193,Miami (OH),17
201,Oklahoma,34,2306,Kansas State,41
52,Florida State,44,103,Boston College,14
166,New Mexico State,45,62,Hawai'i,26
2433,Louisiana Monroe,21,309,Louisiana,17
204,Oregon State,14,30,USC,17
252,BYU,38,2751,Wyoming,24
9,Arizona State,13,254,Utah,34
264,Washington,40,24,Stanford,22
23,San José State,34,2711,Western Michigan,6
2579,South Carolina,50,2569,South Carolina State,10
252,BYU,38,328,Utah State,26
248,Houston,24,2655,Tulane,27
2393,Middle Tennessee,30,2636,UT San Antonio,45
68,Boise State,35,21,San Diego State,13
26,UCLA,40,264,Washington,32
2439,UNLV,31,167,New Mexico,20
145,Ole Miss,22,96,Kentucky,19
103,Boston College,34,97,Louisville,33
2306,Kansas State,37,2641,Texas Tech,28
2005,Air Force,13,2426,Navy,10
235,Memphis,24,218,Temple,3
2628,TCU,55,201,Oklahoma,24
275,Wisconsin,10,356,Illinois,34
2294,Iowa,14,130,Michigan,27
135,Minnesota,10,2509,Purdue,20
349,Army,14,2247,Georgia State,31
256,James Madison,40,326,Texas State,13
2050,Ball State,44,2459,Northern Illinois,38
2199,Eastern Michigan,20,113,UMass,13
254,Utah,42,204,Oregon State,16
58,South Florida,28,151,East Carolina,48
213,Penn State,17,77,Northwestern,7
239,Baylor,25,197,Oklahoma State,36
2026,Appalachian State,49,2643,The Citadel,0
2305,Kansas,14,66,Iowa State,11
2084,Buffalo,24,193,Miami (OH),20
194,Ohio State,49,164,Rutgers,10
276,Marshall,28,2241,Gardner-Webb,7
153,North Carolina,41,259,Virginia Tech,10
52,Florida State,21,154,Wake Forest,31
120,Maryland,27,127,Michigan State,13
8,Arkansas,26,333,Alabama,49
41,Connecticut,19,278,Fresno State,14
2006,Akron,28,189,Bowling Green,31
2649,Toledo,38,2117,Central Michigan,17
2309,Kent State,31,195,Ohio,24
249,North Texas,45,2226,Florida Atlantic,28
344,Mississippi State,42,245,Texas A&M,24
309,Louisiana,17,6,South Alabama,20
183,Syracuse,59,2681,Wagner,0
265,Washington State,28,25,California,9
2711,Western Michigan,44,160,New Hampshire,7
2429,Charlotte,35,2638,UTEP,41
295,Old Dominion,24,2335,Liberty,38
202,Tulsa,21,2132,Cincinnati,31
2,Auburn,17,99,LSU,21
2032,Arkansas State,45,2433,Louisiana Monroe,28
324,Coastal Carolina,34,290,Georgia Southern,30
98,Western Kentucky,27,2653,Troy,34
242,Rice,28,5,UAB,24
150,Duke,38,258,Virginia,17
2751,Wyoming,16,23,San José State,33
142,Missouri,22,61,Georgia,26
251,Texas,38,277,West Virginia,20
228,Clemson,30,152,NC State,20
158,Nebraska,35,84,Indiana,21
166,New Mexico State,7,2229,Florida International,21
221,Pittsburgh,21,59,Georgia Tech,26
12,Arizona,43,38,Colorado,20
30,USC,42,9,Arizona State,25
2483,Oregon,45,24,Stanford,27
57,Florida,52,331,Eastern Washington,17
2116,UCF,41,2567,SMU,19
164,Rutgers,13,158,Nebraska,14
235,Memphis,32,248,Houston,33
2440,Nevada,14,36,Colorado State,17
23,San José State,40,2439,UNLV,7
57,Florida,24,142,Missouri,17
120,Maryland,29,2509,Purdue,31
2711,Western Michigan,23,2199,Eastern Michigan,45
99,LSU,13,2633,Tennessee,40
344,Mississippi State,40,8,Arkansas,17
201,Oklahoma,0,251,Texas,49
258,Virginia,17,97,Louisville,34
84,Indiana,10,130,Michigan,31
2305,Kansas,31,2628,TCU,38
189,Bowling Green,7,2084,Buffalo,38
2247,Georgia State,41,290,Georgia Southern,33
195,Ohio,55,2006,Akron,34
2132,Cincinnati,28,58,South Florida,24
197,Oklahoma State,41,2641,Texas Tech,31
113,UMass,24,2335,Liberty,42
221,Pittsburgh,45,259,Virginia Tech,29
61,Georgia,42,2,Auburn,10
2426,Navy,53,202,Tulsa,21
26,UCLA,42,254,Utah,32
193,Miami (OH),27,2309,Kent State,24
5,UAB,41,2393,Middle Tennessee,14
77,Northwestern,7,275,Wisconsin,42
2655,Tulane,24,151,East Carolina,9
2459,Northern Illinois,32,2649,Toledo,52
2117,Central Michigan,16,2050,Ball State,17
127,Michigan State,20,194,Ohio State,49
59,Georgia Tech,23,150,Duke,20
9,Arizona State,45,264,Washington,38
238,Vanderbilt,28,145,Ole Miss,52
2390,Miami,24,153,North Carolina,27
2636,UT San Antonio,31,98,Western Kentucky,28
326,Texas State,36,2026,Appalachian State,24
2653,Troy,27,2572,Southern Mississippi,10
2229,Florida International,12,41,Connecticut,33
2032,Arkansas State,20,256,James Madison,42
167,New Mexico,14,2751,Wyoming,27
328,Utah State,34,2005,Air Force,27
2348,Louisiana Tech,41,2638,UTEP,31
30,USC,30,265,Washington State,14
87,Notre Dame,28,252,BYU,20
154,Wake Forest,45,349,Army,10
66,Iowa State,9,2306,Kansas State,10
356,Illinois,9,2294,Iowa,6
96,Kentucky,14,2579,South Carolina,24
103,Boston College,3,228,Clemson,31
2433,Louisiana Monroe,21,324,Coastal Carolina,28
```

. . . and here's the code:

```
// A program to rank teams based strictly on current season performance and quality of opponents
// use "gcc Rankings.c -std=c99 -lm"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

// Parse the data csv file and store into array of structs

typedef struct Data
{
int iA_ID;
char cA_Name [30];
int iA_Points;
int iB_ID;
char cB_Name [30];
int iB_Points;
char placeholder [];
}data; // Make 'data' the alias for struct Data

int main(void)
{
// Obtain a count of games played
FILE *ptr;
char c;
int games=-1;
// Open the file for reading and count the number of games played
ptr = fopen("data.csv", "r");
if (ptr == NULL)
{
    printf("Can't open file!");
    return 0;
}
// Read from the file until end-of-file is reached
for (c = getc(ptr); c != EOF; c = getc(ptr))
{
    if (c == '\n') // Increment games count if this character is newline
    games++;
}
system("clear");
printf("The number of games played is %d\n",games);
// Close the file
fclose(ptr);
ptr = NULL;

// Initialize the file pointer
FILE *pF=fopen("data.csv", "r");  // Open in read mode
if(!pF)
{
    printf("Can't open file!");
    return 0;
}   
char buff[4096];  // Stores the scores into buff
int rows = 0;
int fields = 0;
data values[games+1];  // Array of structs to store values  

int i = 0;
while(fgets(buff, 80, pF))
{
    fields = 0;
    rows++;
    if(rows == 1) continue;  // Do not take the labels

    char *field = strtok(buff, ",");
    while(field)
    {
        if(fields == 0)
        values[i].iA_ID=atoi(field);
        if(fields == 1)
        strcpy(values[i].cA_Name, field);
        if(fields == 2)
        values[i].iA_Points=atoi(field);
        if(fields == 3)
        values[i].iB_ID=atoi(field);
        if(fields == 4)
        strcpy(values[i].cB_Name, field);
        if(fields == 5)
        values[i].iB_Points=atoi(field);
        field = strtok(NULL, ",");  // update
        fields++;
    }
    i++;
}
fclose(pF);
pF=NULL;

// Create a function to print all the values of the array of structs
//void printValues (data values[])
//{ 
    //for(int i=0; i<games; i++)
    //{
    //  printf("%d\t %s\t %d\t %d\t %s\t %d\n", values[i].iA_ID, values[i].cA_Name, values[i].iA_Points, values[i].iB_ID, values[i].cB_Name, values[i].iB_Points);
    //}
//}
//printValues(values); // Call the function

int scores[2*games][6]; // Column 4 is top-level Evaluated checklist; 5 is #games team B played
float factors[2*games][3]; // Column 0 is score factors; column 1 is team factors; column 2 is holding place for team factors during preliminary run
int ATeam=0, BTeam, CTeam, AGames=0, BGames=0, CGames=0, ARows=0, BRows=0, CRows=0, n=0;
float AFactor=0.0, BFactor=0.0, CFactor=0.0;
float cbrtf(float arg), factormin=10;


int iPreference=0;
printf("\n1\tCube root of (Points scored by Team A + 3)/(Points scored by Team B + 3)\n");
printf("2\tFraction of game points scored by Team A\n");
printf("3\tln of [(percentage of game points scored by Team A) + 1]\n");
printf("\nPlease select your preference (1-3): ");
scanf("%d", &iPreference);

for (rows=0; rows<games; rows++)
{
    scores[rows][0]=values[rows].iA_ID;
    scores[rows+games][0]=values[rows].iB_ID;
    scores[rows][1]=values[rows].iA_Points;
    scores[rows+games][1]=values[rows].iB_Points;
    scores[rows][2]=values[rows].iB_ID;
    scores[rows+games][2]=values[rows].iA_ID;
    scores[rows][3]=values[rows].iB_Points;
    scores[rows+games][3]=values[rows].iA_Points;
    scores[rows][4]=0;  // Column 4 will be checked off with a '1' once a game has been evaluated
    scores[rows+games][4]=0;
    factors[rows][1]=1;  // Seed every team with a starting value of 1
    factors[rows+games][1]=1;
    switch (iPreference)
    {
    case 1:
        factors[rows][0]=cbrtf((3+(float)scores[rows][1])/(3+(float)scores[rows][3]));
        factors[rows+games][0]=cbrtf((3+(float)scores[rows+games][1])/(3+(float)scores[rows+games][3]));
    //case 2:
    //  factors[rows][0]=((float)scores[rows][1])/(((float)scores[rows][1])+((float)scores[rows][3]));  
    //  factors[rows+games][0]=((float)scores[rows+games][1])/(((float)scores[rows+games][1])+((float)scores[rows+games][3]));
    //case 3:
    //  factors[rows][0]=log((((float)scores[rows][1])/(((float)scores[rows][1])+((float)scores[rows][3])))+1); 
    //  factors[rows+games][0]=log((((float)scores[rows+games][1])/(((float)scores[rows+games][1])+((float)scores[rows+games][3])))+1);
    }
}

if (isnan(factors[rows][0]))
{
// print the numerator and denominator 
printf("\tNumerator:(%E) / Denominator(%E) = %E\n", (float)scores[rows][1], ((float)scores[rows][1]+(float)scores[rows][3]), (float)scores[rows][0]);
// end the program and review 
exit(0);
}

for (rows=0; rows<2*games; rows++)
    printf("%d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %f\n", scores[rows][0], scores[rows][1], scores[rows][2], scores[rows][3], factors[rows][0]);
printf("\n\n\n");

for (rows=0; rows<2*games; rows++)
{
    if(factors[rows][0]>=factormin) continue;
    factormin=factors[rows][0];
}
printf("Lowest factor calculated is %f\n\n", factormin);

for (rows=0; rows<2*games; rows++) // Work down the scores array until you get to . . .
{
    if(scores[rows][4]==1) continue;  // . . . a team that has not already been evaluated
    ATeam=scores[rows][0]; // Team A (not yet evaluated) becomes ATeam (team under evaluation this run at level A)  
    AFactor=0;
    AGames=0;
    //printf("ATeam = %d\n", ATeam);
    for (ARows=rows; ARows<2*games; ARows++)  // Look through the the remaining games in the scores array for ATeam's games
    {
        if(scores[ARows][0]!=ATeam) continue;  // Skip games in which ATeam didn't play
        BTeam=scores[ARows][2]; // The opposing team becomes the team under evaluation at level B
        AGames=AGames+1;
        BGames=0;
        BFactor=0;
        for (BRows=0; BRows<2*games; BRows++) // Now evaluate strength of opponent BTeam
        {
            if(scores[BRows][0]!=BTeam) continue;  // Skip games in which BTeam didn't play
            CTeam=scores[BRows][2]; // The opposing team becomes the team under evaluation at level C
            BGames=BGames+1;
            CGames=0;
            CFactor=0;
            for (CRows=0; CRows<2*games; CRows++) // Now evaluate strength of each of BTeam's opponents CTeam
            {
                if(scores[CRows][0]!=CTeam) continue;  // Skip games in which CTeam didn't play
                CGames=CGames+1;
                CFactor=CFactor+(factors[CRows][1]*factors[CRows][0]);
            }
            CFactor=CFactor/CGames;  // Cumulative performance of CTeam against its opponents
            BFactor=BFactor+(CFactor*factors[BRows][0]); // Increment BFactor by CTeam's strength x BTeam's performance against it
        }
        BFactor=BFactor/BGames;  // Cumulative performance of BTeam against its opponents
        AFactor=AFactor+(BFactor*factors[ARows][0]); // Increment AFactor by BTeam's strength x ATeam's performance against it
        //printf("AFactor = %f\t AGames = %d\n", AFactor, AGames);
        scores[ARows][4]=1; // Mark this game for ATeam vs BTeam as Evaluated
        //printf("rows = %d\t ARows = %d\n", rows, ARows);
    }       
    AFactor=AFactor/AGames;

    for (n=0; n<2*games; n++)
        {
        if(scores[n][2]!=ATeam) continue;  // Wherever ATeam is the opponent . . . 
        factors[n][2]=AFactor;  // Store AFactor in factors column 2 until preliminary round has been completed
        }
}       
for (i=0; i<2*games; i++)
{
factors[i][1]=factors[i][2]; // Replace starting team value of 1 in column 1 with factor from column 2 to prepare for final evaluation round
//printf("%d\t %f\n", scores[i][2], factors[i][1]);
scores[i][4]=0;  // Remove "evaluated" tag from every game to prepare for round 2       
}

// Begin round 2, now with factors[][1] seeded with AFactor from round 1

for (rows=0; rows<2*games; rows++) // Work down the scores arrahy until you get to . . .
{
    if(scores[rows][4]==1) continue;  // . . . a team that has not already been evaluated
    ATeam=scores[rows][0]; // Team A (not yet evaluated) becomes ATeam (team under evaluation this run at level A)  
    AFactor=0;
    AGames=0;
    //printf("ATeam = %d\n", ATeam);
    for (ARows=rows; ARows<2*games; ARows++)  // Look through the the remaining games in the scores array for ATeam's games
    {
        if(scores[ARows][0]!=ATeam) continue;  // Skip games in which ATeam didn't play
        BTeam=scores[ARows][2]; // The opposing team becomes the team under evaluation at level B
        AGames=AGames+1;
        BGames=0;
        BFactor=0;
        for (BRows=0; BRows<2*games; BRows++) // Now evaluate strength of opponent BTeam
        {
            if(scores[BRows][0]!=BTeam) continue;  // Skip games in which BTeam didn't play
            CTeam=scores[BRows][2]; // The opposing team becomes the team under evaluation at level C
            BGames=BGames+1;
            CGames=0;
            CFactor=0;
            for (CRows=0; CRows<2*games; CRows++) // Now evaluate strength of each of BTeam's opponents CTeam
            {
                if(scores[CRows][0]!=CTeam) continue;  // Skip games in which CTeam didn't play
                CGames=CGames+1;
                CFactor=CFactor+(factors[CRows][1]*factors[CRows][0]);
            }
            CFactor=CFactor/CGames;  // Cumulative performance of CTeam against its opponents
            BFactor=BFactor+(CFactor*factors[BRows][0]); // Increment BFactor by CTeam's strength x BTeam's performance against it
        }
        BFactor=BFactor/BGames;  // Cumulative performance of BTeam against its opponents
        AFactor=AFactor+(BFactor*factors[ARows][0]); // Increment AFactor by BTeam's strength x ATeam's performance against it
        //printf("AFactor = %f\t AGames = %d\n", AFactor, AGames);
        scores[ARows][4]=1; // Mark this game for ATeam vs BTeam as Evaluated
        //printf("rows = %d\t ARows = %d\n", rows, ARows);
    }       
    AFactor=AFactor/AGames;

    for (n=0; n<2*games; n++)
        {
        if(scores[n][2]!=ATeam) continue;  // Wherever ATeam is the opponent . . . 
        scores[n][5]=AGames; // . . . store # games ATeam played in column 5 and . . .
        factors[n][2]=AFactor;  // . . . store AFactor in factors column 2 until round 2 has been completed
        }
}
printf("\n\n\n");

for (i=0; i<games; i++)  // Sort the data by factors
{
if(factors[i][2]>=factors[i+1][2])continue;
else 
    {
    factors[games+1][2]=factors[i+1][2];  // Temporarily "move" the larger factor (w/ id # and school name) to a row beyond the games data
    scores[games+1][2]=scores[i+1][2];
    scores[games+1][5]=scores[i+1][5];
    strcpy(values[games+1].cB_Name, values[i+1].cB_Name);
    
    factors[i+1][2]=factors[i][2];  // "Move" the smaller factor (w/ id # and school name) into the "vacated" cells
    scores[i+1][2]=scores[i][2];
    scores[i+1][5]=scores[i][5];
    strcpy(values[i+1].cB_Name, values[i].cB_Name);
    
    factors[i][2]=factors[games+1][2];  // "Move" the larger factor (w/ id # and school name) to where the smaller had been
    scores[i][2]=scores[games+1][2];
    scores[i][5]=scores[games+1][5];
    strcpy(values[i].cB_Name, values[games+1].cB_Name);
    
    i=0;        
    }
}

n=-1;
for (i=0; i<games; i++)
{
if(scores[i+1][2]==scores[i][2]) continue;  // Skip duplicates
    {
    if(scores[i][5]<4) continue;  // Skip teams that played fewer than 4 games
        {
        n=n+1;
        printf("%d.\t %d\t %.3f\t (%d)\t %s\n", n, scores[i][2], factors[i][2], scores[i][5], values[i].cB_Name);
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you have forgotten to include a listing of your code in your post.

Comment: You also haven't said which programming language you are using. There are many languages that have switch statements, and they do not all behave the same.

Comment: I just added the lines, thanks.  I thought that would be the next box in the posting process.  I'm using C.

Comment: @StevenPatterson Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @Steven Patterson – 
What is `iPreference` set to if you _run_ _with a switch statement_?

Comment: It is set to '1' when I'm trying to get case 1 (the formula that works when the switch is commented out) to work WITH the switch, Armali.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm new to coding. I don't know what I can trim and still have functional code, so I've added the entire program and some of the data file it accesses.  Hopefully you can see that it runs without the switch, and balks with NaNs with the switch.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried commenting out different lines.  The block that scans in iPreference (the switch index) can be uncommented, and Case 1 works fine, but ONLY if Cases 2 and 3 remain commented out.  So the problem apparently resides there.

Comment: Please note that if you don't add a `break;` at the end of each `case`, the execution continues in the next one, so that the values are overwritten.

Comment: Also note the warnings produced by this: https://godbolt.org/z/GcT6911nT I added a couple of comments, removed the data file and used stdin instead (due to online compiler limitations). The rest of the program is the same, but there are no NaNs.

Answer (score 1):

As your cube roots get smaller they may hit the limit for a float which has a range of [3.4*10<sup>-38</sup>, 3.4*10<sup>38</sup>], in which case you'd want to use double and `cbrt()` which will increase the range and avoid dividing by zero.

It may be good to add in a print statement to understand why/when the NaN is occurring:

```
// add this at the top if you don't already have it
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h>


/* place this somewhere after you set factors[rows][0] 
   to stop the program when you hit a NaN.  Remove  
   exit(0) if you want this to continue after computing a NaN
*/
if ( isnan(factors[rows][0]) ) {
     // print the numerator and denominator 
     printf("\tNumerator:(%E) / Denominator(%E) = %E\n", (float)scores[rows][1], ((float)scores[rows][1]+(float)scores[rows][3]), (float)scores[rows][0]);
     // end the program and review 
     exit(0);
}
```

**Update: replaced NaN comparison with isnan from math.h**

Comment: NaNs can't be compared for equality. [isnan](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isnan) is the right function to use.

Comment: Thanks, I should've used isnan() from the beginning.

Comment: Note: Typical non-zero `float` range begins with 1.4E-45f.

Comment: @StevenPatterson Are those the values that are in the data file or the values *actually* used in the calculations?

Comment: Thanks, Michael, Retired Ninja, chux, and phuclv.  I've added the isnan code. I checked, and the smallest factor calculated for the 897 games played was 0.340489. Since Case 1 is ((TeamA score +3)/(TeamB score +3))^-3, even a score of 80 to 0 only gets Case 1 to 3.024 for the winner, and 0.331 for the loser. Case 2 will always be between 0 and 1, and Case 3 between 0 and 0.69.  So going out of the range of floats won't be an issue here, but it's something I'll think about in future coding!

Comment: Thanks, Bob!  I somehow missed that breaks are part of switches!  Adding them allowed me to uncomment the switch, and Case 1 runs without NaNs, as you said!  I was also able to remove the "placeholder" from struct Data without any ill effects.

Comment: Bob, the values in the data file are the ones used in the program, but the file was truncated due to the 50K-character limit, so it didn't include the 0 to 0 score that resulted in the division by zero error I saw.

Answer (score 0):

My switch was missing break statements.  Once I added them, Case 1 ran perfectly.  A single NaN continued to cause Cases 2 and 3 to hang, and I traced it to an acquired error in the data file.  (A 23 to 22 score had changed to a 0 to 0 score, resulting in division by zero.)  When that error was corrected, Cases 2 and 3 ran smoothly as well.